# copy all files from a dir *foobar* into another folder

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to move all files that are returned from:

`c:\blah\:>   dir *foobar*`

into a folder blah\foobar

Answer (score 3):

You could also do `move *foobar* <Destination_Dir>`

Answer (score 0):

From blah\, try:

```
move foobar\* blah\foobar
```

If the second blah doesn't exist, you'll need to create it:

```
mkdir blah
```

If you were in \foobar, you'd want to go:

```
move * ..\blah\foobar
```

as .. represents the folder above the current folder (so `c:\blah\..\blah\.\foobar` boils down to `c:\blah\foobar`)